# How to pass updated object as parameter to UpdateMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, detailsview

I have `DetailsView` where I bind single database record of type `Mas`. SelectMethod get object by id and I can access data like this:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="masDetailView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
SelectMethod="GetMas" UpdateMethod="UpdateMas" ItemType="NSMAS.DAL.Mas"
AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnDataBound="MasDetailViewOnDataBound"> 
 <Fields>
  <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="nameLbl0" Text="Název: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="nameLbl" Text='<%#: Item.MasName %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="nameEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.MasName %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate
  </asp:TemplateField>
<%--other fields--%>
```

When I click autogenerated button for editing `ItemTemplate` is replaced by `EditItemTemplate` so I can edit each column. Now when I click on Update button I access updated fields by getting string value of each `TextBox`.

What I want now is to get object of `Mas` with updated fields so I can do something like this in codebehind:

```
public void UpdateMas(Mas newMas)
{
 using (var ctx = new NSMASEntities())
 {
  //newMas = get the object with updated field here or pass it like parameter (now, newMas=null)              
  Mas oldMas = ctx.Mas.Find(int.Parse(_masId));
  oldMas.MasName = newMas.MasName;
  //other columns
  ctx.SaveChanges();
 }
}
```

What is the way to access updated object so I can simply update the old one?

**EDIT:**

I have figured out that if I replace `'<%#: Item.MasName %>'` with `'<%#: Bind("MasName") %>'` and in codebehind in UpdateMethod like this:

```
Mas mas = ctx.Mas.Find(int.Parse(_masId));
TryUpdateModel(mas);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

But in `Bind("param")`, param cannot be record from another table f.e. `Bind("Region.RegionName")` is not working. Is there another way how to access and bind all fields that are included via foreign key?

Comment: what is the content of `TryUpdateModel` method ? post the code would be help the reader to understand the question

Comment: It is a system method `System.Web.UI.Page.TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel)`. So when data is loaded into BoundField it shows original value. After I click Edit, BoundField is editable. After changing value I click Update and UpdateMethod is called. In this method I have `TryUpdateModel(mas);` which updates data both in database and BoundField. I have few BoundFields but I also need field of some combobox type where user insted of writing can choose from values. But I dont't know how to make some ListBox to work similarly like BoundField (change value in LB -> click Update -> column updated)